# how to access img

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" 
    style="float: left; list-style: none; width: 139px; " jcarouselindex="1">
    <a target="_parent" href="/index.php?option=com_community&amp;view=profile">
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="http://jomsocial.projectstatus.in//landing-page/images/slide_001.png" alt="">
    </a>
</li>

<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal"
    style="float: left; list-style: none; width: 139px; " jcarouselindex="2"> 
    <a href="#"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="http://jomsocial.projectstatus.in//landing-page/images/slide_002.png" alt="">
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to access two images in JQuery.
I wonder how to access them.
For example

```
(.jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal img).roate()
```

dose it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively `<li>` element with class name `.jcarousel-item` you can get image with:

```
$(".jcarousel-item img")
```

In order to access images from lists with class names `.jcarousel-item-1` and `.jcarousel-item-2` only you can use:

```
$(".jcarousel-item-1 img, .jcarousel-item-2 img")
```

Or separately as described in the first example:

```
$(".jcarousel-item-1 img")
$(".jcarousel-item-2 img")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".cloudcarousel");
```

That will get you both images. Each `<img>` has CSS class `cloudcarousel` so the above will select both. If you want to be more specific to ensure they are images, use:

```
$("img.cloudcarousel");
```

which will guarantee they are `<img>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for you answer my question is how I put different effect on two images.  Can I do $(.jcarousel-item-1 img).rotate(10) $(.jcarousel-item-2 img).rotate(30)

Comment: @user1413449 yes if you want to select each individually to manipulate them in different ways, you may want to select them in that way. Otherwise my answer groups them.

Comment: Yes, you can do. And your questions should never be `can I do this` but `I have done this, its not working`

Answer (score 0):

This one also should do the trick.

```
$(".cloudcarousel");
```